# Is there way to track unexpected amount of inputs values with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I generate a list of users that can at any time were changed and each user has an input field and I try to track values that are written there, how can I track all these inputs?

```
users.map((val, idx) => {
    <input type="text" placeholder={val.name} ref={nameRef}></input>
})
```

Comment: Can you include a code example of what you're trying to do? (How is the input handled? is it saved in state?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Usually you'd do this in one of a couple of ways. 1. By holding the user objects in state, rendering an input for each user, and making the change handler for the input update that user object in state (usually by creating on-the-fly change handlers). 2. By having a `Map` or object in state keyed by a unique value from each user, with the value being the value being edited. Then when rendering the inputs, you use the values from the Map/object. When the input changes, you update the Map/object (perhaps using the input's name).

Comment: Okay, I added part of code here, as you can see I tried to use React.useRef()

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I should try, good idea